# After Rails Proc turns a block into an object, why can a class call it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a sample code that turns a block into an object using `Proc.new` so that it can be executed independently. There are two `puts` at the end to print the result, in this example, the array is brought into the block for execution. At this point, I have something that I don't understand.

In the following code, why is `.iterate!(square)` valid? They are the method defined in the class and the name of a separate block object. Why can they be written together?
Second, what is the working process of `def iterate!(code)`? Why is the value being carried into `(code)`? And what are `self` and `code.call` here?

```
square = Proc.new do |n|    
  n ** 2                    
end

class Array
  def iterate!(code)
    self.map {|n| code.call(n)}  
  end
end

puts [1, 2, 3].iterate!(square)
puts [4, 5, 6].iterate!(square)
```

I'm a beginner, please explain as detailed as possible, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
square = Proc.new do |n|    
  n ** 2                    
end
```

This is a simple proc, which expect an integer argument, and return square of the argument.

eg:

```rb
square.call(5)  => 25
square.(5)      => 25
```

Now, You have opened Array class and added `iterate!` method which takes an argument. and the method just work on self (self here refers to same array on which you are calling the iterate method. here self = [1,2,3] in your first case and [4,5,6] in you second case.

in the iterate! method definition, you are mapping/looping the array elements and you are calling the `square` proc with each element as arguments.

So it is more like

```rb
square.call(1) => 1
square.call(2) => 4
square.call(3) => 9
```